# How would I refactor this javascript to not use a global?

Tags: javascript

```
var groups;

function findGroups {
  getGroups().then(function (g) {
    groups = g;
  });
}

function foo() {
  var a = groups[0];  //or something along those lines.
  //access the properties of `g`
}
```

I want to access `g` in other functions throughout the page, so I assigned it to a global variable.  I have been under the impression that globals are bad.  How else would I accomplish this?

Thanks

Edit:  getGroups() is an API call.  I don't want to have to call it multiple times.

Comment: Globals are only bad if you are using them in the wrong way :)

Comment: Okay, so this is what globals are for then right?  I make an API call to get `groups` and I use them in multiple functions.  I don't want to make the API call multiple times.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing in having to call `getGroups()` "*multiple times*"? Because that *feels* like a separate question to the other ("*how can I avoid [global variables]?*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access that variable accross multiple pages establishing a global namespace could be a good way to go:

```
// file1.js (loaded first)
myApp = {}; // global namespace
(function() {
    var groups = {};

    myApp.findGroups = function() {
      return groups;
    };

    // init groups
    (function init() {
        getGroups().then(function (g) {
            groups = g;
        });
    }());
}());

// file2.js (loaded next)
myApp.findGroups(); // now myApp.groups is available
```

Comment: `getGroups( )` is an API call I don't want to make multiple times.  How would I only call it once?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut I edited my answer to have an init block so "getGroups" is only invoked once at the beginning of execution

Answer (score 1):

You can get the function in a closure, so the groups variable will be local:

```
(function(){
    var groups;

    function findGroups {
      getGroups().then(function (g) {
        groups = g;
      });
    }
})();
```

Comment: How would I access the properties of `g` in another function?

Comment: How does this solution help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use OOP style:

```
var Group = {
    groups: null,
    findGroups: function() {
        getGroups().then(function (g) {
            Group.groups = g;
        });
    },
    fetchGroup: function(index){
        return Group.groups[index];
    }

};

Group.findGroups();
var group = Group.fetchGroup(index);
```

Or with constructor:

```
function Group(){
    this.groups = null;
    var self = this;
    this.findGroups = function() {
      getGroups().then(function (g) {
        self.groups = g;
      });
   };
};

var group = new Group();
group.findGroups();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have just one global variable, then you can access data through its public interface.

Example:

```
var myLibrary;

(function (lib) {
    var groups;
    function findGroups() {
        getGroups().then(function (g) {
            groups = g;
        });
    }
    function getLocalGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    //public interface
    lib.findGroups = findGroups;
    lib.getLocalGroups = getLocalGroups;
}(myLibrary));
```